# Is there a point to configure SNAT source address in NAT gateway?

Tags: iptables, nat

Let's say, that one has following network topology:
[image: NAT gateway network settings]

NAT gateway `linux-router` has a following SNAT rule in place:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  10.99.99.50          anywhere             to:1.1.1.6
```

In addition, as seen on the drawing, the `1.1.1.6` address is configured on `lo` interface. Technically, this is not needed, i.e one can delete it and the `linux-svr` still has the connectivity. Thus, is there a point to configure SNAT source address in NAT gateway? Only for troubleshooting purposes as it is easier to associate and trace back `1.1.1.6` to `linux-svr`?

Comment: I get the feeling that this picture might be slightly incomplete. The SNAT rule applies NAT to *outgoing connections* from `linux-svr` and to any incoming responses that belong to these connections. But a server is generally assumed to be there to respond to *incoming* connections. Perhaps on the `linux-router` there is (or used to be) a software load balancer, a reverse proxy, a malware scanner, or some other program that would selectively pass some incoming traffic from the internet to the `linux-svr`?

Comment: Or if `linux-svr`'s role does not require incoming connections from the internet, then the `1.1.1.6` address on `linux-router`'s loopback might be to allow the `1.1.1.6` address to be pingable, while ensuring that no actual incoming traffic from the internet reaches `linux-svr` to trouble it - so if someone attempts a denial-of-service attack to `1.1.1.6`, it may bog down the `linux-router`, but the `linux-svr` behind it should not be affected and would still be fully usable internally.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for the comments! The `linux-svr` role indeed does not require incoming connections from the Internet. The only advantage of having the `1.1.1.6` on `lo` that I see is the same as you mentioned- it allows one to ping/traceroute `1.1.1.6` and thus allows one to easily trace back `1.1.1.6` to `linux-svr`. That's the only point of `1.1.1.6` in the NAT gateway that I can see.

Comment: If there is no other rule in the iptables, then this configuration not only allows for the ip-address 1.1.1.6 to be pinged from the internet but also exposes the internal network of _linux-router_, and therefore all internal services of _linux-router_, to the whole world!!!  I think that is *not* a really smart thing to do.

Comment: @bey0nd Filter table rules both for incoming traffic to `linux-router` and forwarded traffic to `linux-svr` are in place.

Comment: Do those rules filter the incoming/outgoing packages with 1.1.1.6 as a source or destination address? If so, those would be important for the understanding of this configuration. Otherwise, the local interface is exposed to the internet.

Comment: @bey0nd Yes, they do.

Comment: @Martin Can you share/post those rules as they might shad a light on the purpose of this configuration. Besides the performance difference between MASQ and SNAT and that SNAT can deal better with disconnected interfaces, I can't see any other point in this config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*netfilter* is route-agnostic. That's the important thing that explains what happens below. *netfilter*'s NAT handling alters addresses, and in some cases, when this is done before a route decision, this in turn alters the route decision. *netfilter* doesn't do route decisions itself: that's only the role of the routing stack.

I'm assuming below that *linux-router* has no additional *firewalling* rule (in the default *iptables* *filter* table), because it was never mentioned in the question. Also to avoid multiplying cases to address, I'm assuming there's no other system to consider beside *linux-srv* (and *linux-router*) in the 10.99.99.0/24 LAN (it wouldn't be difficult to address them too).

---

### About removing 1.1.1.6

SNAT happens at POSTROUTING, after any routing decision. If SNAT sees an IP matching the given criteria, it will add a conntrack entry to handle replies. Something similar to this happens on *linux-router* (using `conntrack -E -e NEW`):

```
    [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=10.99.99.50 dst=8.8.8.8 sport=57490 dport=80 [UNREPLIED] src=8.8.8.8 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=80 dport=57490
```

It's not *netfilter*'s job to ensure that replies will really come back. That's again the routing stack job (including outside routing where *linux-router* has no control).

Before being deleted, 1.1.1.6 was an IP of *linux-router*. The interface where this IP was added to didn't really matter as Linux is following the [weak host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model): it can answer queries to this IP received on any interface. Removing this entry won't prevent to receive packets for 1.1.1.6 as *M10i* has a specific route to reach 1.1.1.6: using 1.1.215.48 which belongs to *linux-router*. So *linux-router* never gets an ARP request for this IP: the ARP request coming from *M10i* is always 1.1.215.48 (and to tell the same, *M10i*'s ARP table will only have cached 1.1.215.48, not 1.1.1.6). That means that the existence of this IP won't matter: *linux-router* will *always* receive traffic for 1.1.1.6. But now there's a difference:

- if incoming packet doesn't match a previously created conntrack entry

If the packet is not related to previous activity from *linux-srv*, this packet will reach the first *route decision*, as seen in [this schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg). According to its current routing table this should be this:

```
    # ip route get from 198.51.100.101 iif eth0 1.1.1.6
    1.1.1.6 from 198.51.100.101 via 1.1.215.60 dev eth0 
        cache iif eth0
```

If it had been *M10i* (or any system in the 1.1.215.32/27 LAN), *linux-router* would also have added ICMP redirects from time to time, as this can tell:

```
    # ip route get from 1.1.215.60 iif eth0 1.1.1.6
    1.1.1.6 from 1.1.215.60 via 1.1.215.60 dev eth0 
        cache <redirect> iif eth0
```

Anyway, for packets coming from internet, packets will be sent back to *M10i*, which is probably implementing [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2): this routed-back packet will be dropped by *M10i*, since its source (198.51.100.101) is on the wrong side of its routing table and thus filtered by Strict Path Forwarding. Without Strict Reverse Path Forwarding, this would have caused a loop between *M10i* and *linux-router* until the packet's TTL was decremented to 0 and the packet then also dropped.

- If incoming packet *does* match a previously flow NATed and tracked by conntrack.

Previous example: a reply packet received from 8.8.8.8 tcp port 80 to 1.1.1.6 port 57490, which would be tracked by `conntrack -E`:

```
     [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.99.99.50 dst=8.8.8.8 sport=57490 dport=80 src=8.8.8.8 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=80 dport=57490
     [UPDATE] tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=10.99.99.50 dst=8.8.8.8 sport=57490 dport=80 src=8.8.8.8 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=80 dport=57490 [ASSURED]
```

At some pre-routing point, *conntrack* will handle "de-SNAT" (as a reminder, this packet will never even traverse again *iptables*' nat table, this is also written in the previous schematic: *"nat" table only consulted for "NEW" connections*). The destination IP is now changed to 10.99.99.50, and the packet reaches the first route decision: it gets routed to *linux-srv*. Everything works fine.

So I explained what happens when you remove 1.1.1.6: doesn't affect *linux-srv* as an internet client, but creates some minor disruption between *M10i* and *linux-router* for unrelated ingress packets.

If you want some clients on internet to reach *linux-srv* using a DNAT rule on *linux-router*, then for the affected connections (eg: a web server on *linux-srv* tcp port 80), everything will work without disruption. For other attempts, again there's the minor issue between *M10i* and *linux-router*.

---

### About removing the source IP selector/filter to the SNAT rule

An  information wasn't provided: if there's also a selector/filter on the outgoing interface, or not. The two rules below would get the same output from `iptables -t nat -n -L` (but not from `iptables -t nat -n -v -L` or better `iptables-save`):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.99.99.254 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.6
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.99.99.254 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.6
```

Actually it won't matter in this case if you now use either of these two commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.6
```

- with 1.1.1.6 still belonging to *linux-router*

Because a private IP destination address cannot be seen coming on the wire from eth0's side, *linux-router* can effectively only route *one* IP address: *linux-srv*'s 10.99.99.50 and this routing can only happen when it's initiated from 10.99.99.50 first, so that it's SNATed to a public IP. Since *iptables* will create a new conntrack entry only on initial connection (state NEW), after this the conntrack entry won't be changed anymore and everything will work fine.

- with 1.1.1.6 removed from *linux-router*
- For *linux-srv* everything will still work as expected when it connects to Internet: the previous explanation also applies.
- For any unknown incoming connection from outside to 1.1.1.6 (eg, from 198.51.100.101):

  Routing stack determines that 1.1.1.6 should be routed to *M10i* (see explanation made earlier). A tentative conntrack entry is added in state NEW and the packet reaches nat/POSTROUTING: packet is SNATed to 1.1.1.6 and sent back to *M10i*. *M10i* has a route to 1.1.1.6 and sends again the alterned packet to *linux-router* with both source and destination IP as 1.1.1.6 (as source is on the correct side of its routing tables, it's not even dropped by Strict Reverse Path Forwarding). *linux-router* receives a packet ... from there I can't tell if it's a bug or not but here's what's captured in an experiment reproducing your case with `conntrack -E`, with a single TCP SYN packet received from 198.51.100.101:

  ```
       # conntrack -E
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=198.51.100.101 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=48202 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=48202
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=48202 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=60062
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=60062 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=23442
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=23442 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=54429
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=54429 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=7652
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=7652 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=34503
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=34503 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=49256
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=49256 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=58399
           [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=58399 dport=5555 [UNREPLIED] src=1.1.1.6 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=5555 dport=54522
           [...]
  ```

  Even if the netfilter's behaviour isn't normal, there's really a loop happening between *M10i* and *linux-router* (till TTL drops to 0).

---

### Conclusion

Don't remove the local IP address 1.1.1.6. You're creating routing problems, and it's not *netfilter*'s role to correct those routing problems. Even if you add firewalling rules preventing those loops, that's not a sane behaviour to use incorrect routes.

Likewise, you could choose to remove the source IP selector for the SNAT rule, but better not if there is also no interface selected: (ie if you chose this rule: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.6`). it's only working because there are private IP addresses, non-routable on Internet, in play. If that were not the case, any connection from outside trying to reach the LAN behind *linux-router*'s eth2 interface would be SNATed to 1.1.1.6.

That would also be the case for example if you added a DNAT rule to have some services from *linux-srv* reachable from Internet, preventing *linux-srv* to ever see a source address different from 1.1.1.6. Here's a concrete example in a simulation (with a sane restoration of 1.1.1.6 to *linux-router*):

```
# ip -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 1.1.1.6/32 
eth0@if5         UP             1.1.215.48/27 
eth2@if4         UP             10.99.99.254/24 

# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.6 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.99.50

# iptables-save | grep -v ^#
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.6/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.99.99.50
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.6
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

# conntrack -E 
   [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=198.51.100.101 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=45752 dport=80 [UNREPLIED] src=10.99.99.50 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=80 dport=45752
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=198.51.100.101 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=45752 dport=80 src=10.99.99.50 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=80 dport=45752
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=198.51.100.101 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=45752 dport=80 src=10.99.99.50 dst=1.1.1.6 sport=80 dport=45752 [ASSURED]
```

While it might not be clear, that means the expected replies are from 10.99.99.50 to 1.1.1.6 (not to 198.51.100.101): *linux-srv* stays blind on which IP address really connected to it, it will always see 1.1.1.6.